# Merge request: [cpupower-command] -> [cpupower]

Tags: discussion, tag-merge

I found a weird tag: [cpupower-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpupower-command). I looked at whether there was an already existing [cpupower](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpupower) tag and there was not. There is no good reason why [cpupower-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpupower-command) should not be [cpupower](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpupower). I changed the only question's tag to my newly created [cpupower](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpupower).

Please could we have [cpupower-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpupower-command) merged into [cpupower](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpupower)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have removed the only question tagged [cpupower-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpupower-command), it will go away some time around 04:00 UTC tomorrow. No reason to make it a synonym or anything else after that. Also, do remember to [add a tag excerpt or wiki](https://askubuntu.com/edit-tag-wiki/8634) to the tag you created.

Answer (score 2):

I think this command isn’t worth an own tag at all – [a quick search](https://www.startpage.com/do/search?q=site%3Aaskubuntu.com+cpupower&rl=vd&lui=english) showed just a bunch of questions *mentioning* the command, not more.

I vote to delete the tag(s).